# How to inherit from a class that has been declared forwardly

Tags: c++, inheritance, header-files, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

I have declared classes: `Another` and `Klass`.
class `Another` is only defined in `another.hpp`, class `Klass` is declared in `klass.hpp` and defined in `klass.cpp`.

I have included `another.hpp` inside `klass.cpp` and forward-declared class `Another` in `klass.hpp`.

```
// klass.cpp
#include "klass.hpp"
#include "another.hpp"

Klass::Klass()
{

}

// klass.hpp
#pragma once

class Another;

class Klass : public Another
{
public:
    Klass();
};

// another.hpp
#pragma once

class Another
{
protected:
    int a;
    char b;
};
```

Comment: Just include `another.hpp` in `klass.hpp`.

Comment: @眠りネロク I already know that I can do that way, but I'm just asking If I can do it by my way.

Comment: You can't. Your way is a non-starter. C++ requires classes be completely defined when inherited from. It looks to me like you have another underlying problem. But you ask about your perceived solution instead of the actual problem.

Comment: it's the actual problem. I'm having this problem in a project I'm working on. I just created sample classes to ask you.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica If it's impossible for inheriting without including in hpp, then okay. Thank you! I just heard a lot that it's not good to include in header file and instead you should include all in cpp and forward declare in hpp.

Comment: @RoarRaizZer the recommendation is to use a foward declaration when you **can**. When you want to inherit you cannot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file `klass.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

class Another;

class Klass : public Another
{
public:
    Klass();
};
```

`class Another;` is a forward declaration: It just introduces the name `Another` into a C++ scope. This forward declaration simply includes a partial classification of the name `Another` (i.e., that it is about a class). It doesn't provide all the details for creating a complete declaration (e.g., it doesn't give the details for inferring its size).

As such, `Another` above is an *incomplete type* and its size is unknown to the compiler. Therefore, you can't provide a definition of the class `Klass` by inheriting from `Another`, an incomplete type. If you could, what should be then the size of `Klass`?.

Comment: Can you tell me why it's a best practice to include header files in cpp and forward declare it in header? I know that it prevents from including unnecessary header files when you include this header file but is there any other subtleties?

Comment: I'm not encouraging you to forward declare `Another` in `klass.hpp`, but to include in a header file all the needed dependencies. For example, `Klass` does depend on `Another` since `Klass` inherits from `Another`, so `Another` is a dependency of `Klass`. Therefore, I would simply write `#include "another.hpp"` in `klass.hpp` and no forward declaration at all of `Another` (the full declaration of `Another` would be included in `klass.hpp` this way). I hope it helps.